# linked streams across dynamic maps

Tags: holoviews

I have a set of hyperspectral data, a grid of X,Y,Energy where each point is a full spectrum.  From those spectra I can create image stacks e.g. image stack 1= sum of counts from channel 600-650 across the grid, image stack 2 = 700-750 etc.

I would like to be able to display the image stacks and when a user clicks on a pixel or adjusts the kdim slider show the full spectrum at that X,Y, Energy point.

At the moment I can show a single image stack and update the spectrum on a click or when changing kdim using the proof of principle code example below.
That's already pretty good but if I increases the number of images (nimages variable in the code) and try and create multiple SingleTap streams  I get an error due to the multiple clash on the ['x', 'y'] parameters.  I looked at the link_inputs in the "responding to events" section but that operates on a clone and I've tried and failed to set it up across dynamic maps.   Could someome provide an example or point me in the right direction on how to do this ?

```
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
hv.extension('bokeh')

def image_extract(energy=0):
    # create a random image as a substitute for looking up the
    # real data 
    return hv.Image(np.random.rand(10,10))

def extract_curve(x=0,y=0,energy=0):
    # create a random curve as a substitute for looking up
    # the real data
    x=np.arange(1000)
    return hv.Curve((x,np.random.rand(1000)),"Counts","channels")

# number of images 
nimages = 1

dmap_list=[]
pointer_list=[]
for i in range(nimages):
    img_dmap = hv.DynamicMap(image_extract, kdims=['energy']).redim.range(energy=(0,90))
    pointer = hv.streams.SingleTap(x=0,y=0, source=img_dmap,subscribers=[],transient=False)
    pointer_list.append(pointer)
    pointer_dmap = hv.DynamicMap(lambda x,y: hv.Points([(x, y)]), streams=[pointer])
    img =img_dmap*pointer_dmap
    dmap_list.append(img)
dmap_list.append(hv.DynamicMap(extract_curve,kdims=['energy'],streams=pointer_list).redim.range(energy=(0,90)))

layout = hv.Layout(tuple(dmap_list)).cols(2)
layout
```

Answer (score 0):

It uses hover rather than clicking, but it sounds like you want to do what's in http://datashader.org/topics/landsat.html :

```
tap = hv.streams.PointerXY(source=true_color)
spectrum_curve = hv.DynamicMap(spectrum, streams=[tap]).redim.range(Luminance=(0, 30000))

tiles * regrid(true_color) + spectrum_curve
```